# MVC Blazor onClick only works in root, not in sub directory

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I have onClick function on a button in my Blazor page, it works fine in root for example in http://localhost/?c=25 the onclick function works fine but when i load the same page in sub-folder, or any other sub-folder pages, the onlick does not work for example in http://localhost/home/index?c=25 it does not work.

My code in following:

Program.cs

```
using TestBlazorMvc.Data;
using TestBlazorMvc.DBContext;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<ProductsService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CategoriesService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapBlazorHub();

app.Run();
```

onClick Function

```
                <p><<button @onclick="FilterList" >Search button</button></p>
```

onClick Event

```
    private async Task FilterList(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Testing...!");
    items = await Task.Run(() => productService.GetProductsByPrice());
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

MVC Page

```
    @{
     ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
 }
<div >
@(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<TestBlazorMvc.Views.Shared.Component.ListItems>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered,new {  Data= " Hello World " }))
    <script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script> 

</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: From what I can see you're loading a Blazor Component in a Razor page.   All routing is being done by the server side routing engine.  "when i load the same page in sub-folder" doesn't make much sense.  Do you mean when I load the same component in another page?  What is the relevance of `?c=25` in the question?  Have you checked Developer tools in the browser to see if there are any clues?

Comment: by sub-folder i mean sub-directory e.g. /home/index/?c=25 which is Not my root as localhost/.  What i mean is, when i load the same component as localhost/ onclick button works! but when i load the same component in browser as localhost/home/index/ the onclick does not work!   You can also notice that normally localhost/ normally refers to localhost/home/index/ in MVC.

Comment: When you load the MVC page in the sub directory check the Developer tools in the Browser F12 and check for script errors.  What do you see?

Comment: i checked Developer tools, there is no error on it, i am getting same results in Developer tools on the page where onclick is working, and the same results on the page where onlick is not working.

Comment: So are you saying `FilterTask` is getting called in one and not in the other?

Comment: I dont know what FilterTask is.

Comment: Apologies `FilterList`.

Comment: Yes that is right, FilterList function is called in localhost/ and when i load the same page from localhost/home/index/ it is not called.

Comment: Does below answer useful to you?

Comment: yes it have fixed the problem, i have accepted it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to routing and having a base url when Blazor (SPA) is used. To solve the issue...

Change `<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`

To `<script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>`

And add a `<base>` element at the top of your _Layout.cshtml file, like this:

```
<head>
   <base href="~/" />
```

Note:

Don't use `Task.Run`

Just do:

```
items = await productService.GetProductsByPrice();
```

If `productService.GetProductsByPrice` is not asyncronous, do:

items = productService.GetProductsByPrice();

followed by: `await Task.CompletedTask;`
if you still want your `FilterList` method to remain asyncronous

Also, the call to the `StateHasChanged` method is superfluous, as it is automatically called by the framework when a UI event is triggered (When you click on the `Search button`, the 'click' event is triggered).

Comment: thank you very much enet, i got my onlick working the way i want, the only problem i am getting is, the blazor component contents are duplicated and added to the botton of the component when i click on the button, so i have [component contents] followed by [duplicate component contents] underneath it after pressing onlick.

Comment: so it seems like it is duplicating the blazor component after onlick. and the onlick changes/results are not reflected on the orignal component.

Comment: i fixed it, i had another <script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>  is another file, i removed it and left it only in Layout.cshtml and everything works fine now, the onlick is working perfectly and there are no duplicated, thanks a million for your solutions.